# Proper way to add delay in my code execution

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to make a very simple logic game. The idea is to see a matrix with a certain number of colored squares(buttons) then to hide them and the player has to click the colored squares. So I need a 2 second delay between the painting the squares/buttons and returning the original colors. All the code is implemented in a `button_click` event.

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int[,] tempMatrix = new int[3, 3];
    tempMatrix = MakeMatrix();
    tempMatrix = SetDifferentValues(tempMatrix);
    SetButtonColor(tempMatrix, 8);
    if (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
       // ReturnButtonsDefaultColor();
    }
    ReturnButtonsDefaultColor();
    Thread.Sleep(2000);

    tempMatrix = ResetTempMatrix(tempMatrix);
}
```

This is the whole code, but what I need is to have some delay between calling `SetButtonColor()` and `ReturnButtonsDefaultColor()`. All my experiments with `Thread.Sleep()` meet no success till now. I get a delay at some point, but the colored squares/buttons are never shown.

Comment: It is not going to paint the UI until the code is complete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't see the buttons change color because the `Sleep` call prevents messages from being processed.

Probably the easiest way to handle this is with a timer. Initialize the timer with a 2 second delay and make sure that it's disabled by default. Then, your button click code enables the timer. Like this:

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do stuff here
    SetButtonColor(...);
    timer1.Enabled = true; // enables the timer. The Elapsed event will occur in 2 seconds
}
```

And your timer's Elapsed event handler:

```
private void timer1_TIck(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = false;
    ResetButtonsDefaultColor();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can always use TPL, its the simplest solution, because you don't need to handle thread contexts or fragment your code.

```
private async void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int[,] tempMatrix = new int[3, 3];
    tempMatrix = MakeMatrix();
    tempMatrix = SetDifferentValues(tempMatrix);
    SetButtonColor(tempMatrix, 8);
    if (true)
    {
       await Task.Delay(2000);
       // ReturnButtonsDefaultColor();
    }
    ReturnButtonsDefaultColor();
       await Task.Delay(2000);

    tempMatrix = ResetTempMatrix(tempMatrix);
}
```

Comment: No, as soon as the code reaches to an await the function will return, and the UI thread released. When the delay is over the execution will continue on the UI thread

Answer (score 2):

Use a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx). Instead of your Thread.Sleep Start() the timer, in the tick event call ReturnButtonsDefaultColor(). You could use a second timer instead of the second Thread.Sleep or save some sort of state and use it in the tick event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tasks:

```
        private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int[,] tempMatrix = new int[3, 3];
            tempMatrix = MakeMatrix();
            tempMatrix = SetDifferentValues(tempMatrix);
            SetButtonColor(tempMatrix, 8);

            Task.Factory.StartNew(
                () => 
                {
                    if (true)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        // ReturnButtonsDefaultColor();
                    }
                    ReturnButtonsDefaultColor(); //Need to dispatch that to the UI thread
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);

                    tempMatrix = ResetTempMatrix(tempMatrix); //Probably that as well
                });
        }
```

Dispatching in WPF is different from Winforms, it should be easy enough to google ;)