# Creating a pause in between code execution?

Tags: c#

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("UserName").InnerText = user;
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Password").InnerText = pass;
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("btnLogin").InvokeMember("Click");
Thread.Sleep(2000);
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("games").InvokeMember("Click");
```

This code right here does not work at all. Basically what i need is a "wait period" in between the time the webbrowser hits the button to login and the time it hits the games tab. This is because it hits the login button and tries to hit the games tab before the page has even loaded, triggering a null error.

[Proper way to add delay in my code execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588447/proper-way-to-add-delay-in-my-code-execution)

I've looked at many threads like this and they all advise to use Thread.Sleep() which does not work. When i try to use timers the code continues to blow right throught and not wait at all. I am looking to create a pause between the 2 segments of code that will wait until the page is loaded, then click the games tab.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? an automated client test?

Comment: If you are doing an automated client test, which framework are you using? I would strongly recommend you to DO NOT use `Thread.Sleep()`

Comment: you should look for Document_Complete event of web browser control.

Comment: Side note: avoid extensive "searched a lot" and "PLEASE" text to your post as it don't provide additional information about your problem. Instead consider adding links to articles you've tried with explanations why it did not solve your problem.

Comment: I've edited my post and would appreciate any help i could get

Comment: What is the type of `webBrowser1`?

Answer (score 1):

You may use `WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted` event for this. [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Occurs when the WebBrowser control finishes loading a document.

Coding example :

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted+= new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(ActivateGameButon); // < = Bind the event to occur when Document id fully loaded 

// You can define what to occur inside the event
void ActivateGameButon(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  // This happens after document is fully loaded

   HtmlElement gameElement;

   // To be on safe side, we check for element existence too
   if((gameElement=webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("games"))!=null){
       gameElement.InvokeMember("Click");
   }

}
```

Comment: Good starting point. Generally should not help OP as in most cases dynamic portion of the page would be created way after that event.